# Dynamic form generation with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am building an AngularJS application where forms will be generated through a pre-defined template. The template will have text input fields and after generation, the user may add/remove text fields.  The html file is as follows:

```
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SdvCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="subdivision in circles">
    <input ng-model="subdivision.location" type="text" />
    <input ng-model="subdivision.firstName" type="text" />
    <input ng-model="subdivision.lastName" type="text" />
    <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeSubdivision()">-
    </button>
</div> 
<a href="#" ng-click="addSubdivision()">Add</a>


 <pre>
    {{ circles| json }}
 </pre>

</div>
</body>
```

The js file is as below:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('SdvCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.circles = [{
      location: null,
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null
  }];

  $scope.addSubdivision = function () {
      $scope.circles.push({
          location: null,
          firstName: null,
          lastName: null
      });
  };

  $scope.removeSubdivision = function () {
      $scope.circles.splice(-1,1);
   };
 });
```

My problem is instead of hard-coding the form field names in the html file, I want to keep them in a text file as template I.e, `[formName: circle, fields: {'location','firstName','lastName'}], [formName: devblock, fields: {'nameOfblock','noOfBlock','villageName'}].` These form names will come in a drop-down box and on selecting a form name, the corresponding form will be generated. Any guidance will be very helpful.

Comment: did you check angularjs custom directives?

Comment: did you hear anything about `ng-form`?